# relation "authentication_user" does not exist on multiple databases

Tags: python, django, database, multiple-databases

i need some help I'm using multiple database and i have a custom user, now i wanted to save users on database and i want to save other models on another database but i got that error: **django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "authentication_user" does not exist**

```
class AuthRouter:
    route_app_labels = {
        "auth",
        "contenttypes",
        "sessions",
        "authentication",
        "core",
        "admin",
    }

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return "core_db"
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return "core_db"
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the auth or contenttypes apps is
        involved.
        """
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
            or obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the auth and contenttypes apps only appear in the
        'auth_db' database.
        """
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == "core_db"
        return None
```

**now that is my ticket router :**

```
class TicketRouter:
    route_app_labels = {"ticket"}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return "ticket_db"
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return "ticket_db"
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the auth or contenttypes apps is
        involved.
        """
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
            or obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the auth and contenttypes apps only appear in the
        'auth_db' database.
        """
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == "ticket_db"
        return None
```

**and here is my ticket model:**

```
class Ticket(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=False, blank=True)

    type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=1)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)
    impact = models.IntegerField(choices=IMPACT_CHOICES, default=1)
    emergency = models.IntegerField(choices=EMERGENCY_CHOICES, default=1)

    priority = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=False, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=False, blank=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    closed_at = models.DateTimeField()

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=SET_NULL,
        blank=False,
        null=True,
        related_name="ticket_created_by",
    )
```

**settings:**

```
    "core_db": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": env("CORE_DB_NAME"),
        "USER": env("CORE_DB_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": env("CORE_DB_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": env("CORE_DB_HOST"),
        "PORT": env("CORE_DB_PORT"),
    },
    "ticket_db": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": env("TICKET_DB_NAME"),
        "USER": env("TICKET_DB_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": env("TICKET_DB_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": env("TICKET_DB_HOST"),
        "PORT": env("TICKET_DB_PORT"),
    },

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "authentication.User"

DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    "routers.db_routers.AuthRouter",
    "routers.db_routers.TicketRouter",
]
```